# Insert AdSense ad to website using Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, adsense, content-script

I'm trying to insert AdSense ad to website using Chrome Extension's content script.
My code looks like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.innerHTML = '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-*************" data-ad-slot="*********" data-ad-format="auto"></ins> <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>';
```

But it shows no ads. Of course, I set manifest file's "matches" field correctly, I have experience with content scripts, but never worked with AdSense.

And yes, I know Google is not affirmative with this way of inserting ads, but I do this for an friend who thinks it is OK, so I don't care, I just wish to show his ads in that div.

Thanks